# "Failed to decode downloaded font" after concatenating all the .css ressources

Tags: css, fonts, gulp

I have lot of CSS ressources for my website.

I decided to use gulp to concatenate all of them, by doing the following :

```
gulp.task('concat_style', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./public/adminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                  './public/adminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css',
                  './public/adminLTE/dist/css/skins/skin-red.min.css',
                  './public/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css',
                  './public/stylesheets/ionicons.min.css',
                  /*and many more*/])
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/stylesheets/'));
});
```

NB: I know I could reference all the .css files with a wildcard expression but I first though my problem was caused by the order by which they were concatened, so I referenced them in the same order they are in my non-concatened version.

In the concatened version I get the following error :

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

The link : `http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` works when I access it with my browser.

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: that's not the error. The font can be *accessed* just fine. The error is about the fact that the font cannot be decoded properly, e.g. it is corrupted or has bad values set in it. Does your font-face declare the resource as being of format woff2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was concatenating my css with the default `concat` function of gulp, and the needed font was required by an `@import` directive (that must always be on top of css file, but was in the middle of the concatened css file).

I ended up using `gulp-concat-css`, it solved the problem